# Translating clauses relating to observation

Tags: translation

If someone says, *I saw him eat the food*, how would one translate it? My best guess is *Mi vidis, ke li manĝantis la manĝaĵon*.

Answer (score 7):

You can just say *Mi vidis lin manĝi la manĝaĵon.*

A close alternative is *Mi vidis lin manĝantan la manĝaĵon.*

Obviously you could substitute *nutraĵon* or a more specific word if you didn't like the repetition of *manĝ-*.

Your guess means "I saw that someone was (in the process of) eating the food." *Iu* means "someone" and the *-ant-* reinforces the idea that the action was ongoing. "Someone had eaten it" is *Iu jam manĝis ĝin* or *Iu manĝintis ĝin.*

Comment: To back up the suggestion with some examples, you can search for " vidis [lŝ]in [a-zĥŝĝĉĵŭ]+i\b " en tekstaro.com. There are many results, for example "Mi neniam vidis ŝin plori" from La Ŝtona Urbo.

Comment: *Mi vidis lin mangxanta" works as well; the nuance between this and "mi vidis lin mangxantan" is somewhat subtle; with the -n means I saw him, who was eating (adjective agreement), and without the -n means I saw him when he was eating (predicate nominative). I wish I could explain this a little clearer, but I'm not succeeding very well :-/.

Comment: Whoops! I'll edit my question to make the sentence match.